# SSIS : I am trying to get the error column name using the script component. However I get error for the code below

Tags: ssis, sql-server-data-tools

I am trying to get the error column name using the script component but am getting an error for the below line:

```
var componentMetaData130 = this.ComponentMetaData as IDTSComponentMetaData130;
Row.ErrorColumnDescription = this.ComponentMetaData.GetIdentificationStringByID(Row.ErrorColumn);
```

> The type or namespace 'IDTSComponentMetaData130' could not be found.

If anyone can guide me for the same.

Answer (score 1):

I don't think "as" is legal syntax in a Script Component. Can you try removing that so the code is:

```
var componentMetaData130 = this.ComponentMetaData;
```

**EDIT:** Ah, my mistake. I think I've found the code you're referring to. Does replacing the "var" with "IDTSComponentMetaData130" work:

```
IDTSComponentMetaData130 componentMetaData = this.ComponentMetaData as IDTSComponentMetaData130;
Row.ErrorColumnName = componentMetaData.GetIdentificationStringByID(Row.ErrorColumn);
```

Comment: This piece of code I have taken from the net and is used to get the column name

Comment: I am using SSDT 2012, I have a doubt its because of that but not sure

Comment: You said you are using SSDT 2012. IDTSComponentMetaData130 is added in SQL Server 2016. Do you have the reference to the right versions of the assemblies?

Comment: @SamKolli : Thank you for clearing the doubt. Is there a way I can add reference to the 2016 assemblies without upgrading. My ultimate goal is to just get the error column name which is much easier in 2016 version.

Comment: I am not sure Shuhom. I would think not. I dont have the set up to test the scenario. I would think two scenarios need to be met; one is the run time that is being targeted. If it is the 2012 version, I am thinking it would not work. Secondly, wonder if the script component project itself lets you add the reference (either manually or by using AssemblyResolve event). If you have the assembly available, please try and let know.

Answer (score 1):

IDTSComponentMetaData130 is SQL Server 2016 and above only.

It is described here: https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/dotnet/api/microsoft.sqlserver.dts.pipeline.wrapper.idtscomponentmetadata130?view=sqlserver-2016

If you go to that link, you'll see a dropdown that shows the available versions.

[image]